# Check if all values are $in an array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB schema called obj that looks like this

```
const objSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  values: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
})
```

I have a MongoDB objects that looks something like

```
{
  id: 1,
  values: "One", "Two", "Three"
}
{
  id: 2,
  values: "One", "Two", "Four"
}
```

I have an array that contains the following values

```
const arr = ["One", "Three"]
```

How can I find all MongoDB Objects that contain ALL elements in arr. So the query would return the object with id 1, but not with id 2.

I am not sure how to use the $in query to achieve this, and I'm not sure if there is another option.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `$all`.

```
db.collection.find({
  "values": {
    $all: [
      "One",
      "Three"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hTKOh06RCu8)**